# Use nginx to block certain requests with regex in location doesn't work

Tags: regex, nginx

We use an Tomcat application which has been migrated to another system. Also attached is a MSSQL report server. The application needs to be read-only eventually. At this moment we still need to enter some data for certain customers. I use nginx so that only one server is needed for both Tomcat service and Report service. Now I'd like to use nginx location method to block certain requests.

With the help of regex101.com I created a regex to use in nginx. I already tried to change the order of the location blocks. However, I can't get it to work. Here's the link to the regex where you can see that only the blocked URL's are colored: https://regex101.com/r/w3oy0M/1/

Here's the code:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name subdomain.domainname.com;

ssl_certificate         c:\cert\public.crt;
ssl_certificate_key     c:\cert\private.rsa;

location / {
    proxy_pass https://subdomain.domainname.com:8443;
}

location ~ "https:\/\/subdomain\.domainname\.com:8443\/(?!.*customer\/510|.*customer\/10638)(.*\/edit|.*\/new|.*\/archive)" {
    # TEST URL FOR NOT ALLOWED REQUESTS
    return 301 https://www.google.com;
}       

location /Reports {
    return 301 https://subdomain.domainname.com:7443/Reports;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
location ~ /.+?(?=customer\/)(?!customer\/510|customer\/10638)(.*\/edit|.*\/new|.*\/archive) {
      # TEST URL FOR NOT ALLOWED REQUESTS
      return 301 https://www.google.com;
}
```

However please note anything after # will be dropped as it's an anchor element so a request like

`https://subdomain.domainname.com/#/customer/521/installations/new` will be sent to nginx as `GET /` and gets routed to your first location block

But, a request like `https://subdomain.domainname.com/hello/customer/521/installations/new` will be routed to https://google.com

Comment: Thanks @ben5556. The conclusion is that there's no option at all to realize this. We'll not edit the source code of the Tomcat application.